# GPS coordinates with Entity framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, gps

So from what I read the Geography SQL type isn't supported in the entity framework yet.

I was wondering if anyone had a solution to a problem I'm having. I have a c# class that has some data access methods using the entity framework and LINQ.
These methods are getting GPS coordinates passed into them. The database (and entity framework types) have longitude and latitude fields on them which are populated when the rows are created. This all works fine.

What I want to do is to make my LINQ queries pull back rows that are near (within a radius) the given GPS coordinates. I don't want to have to start using stored procs as this will be an architecture change.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I'm struggling for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of your database Spatial index (which will allow fast spatial queries), you should store your positions as `Geography` in your table (you can also keep the current latitude/longitude columns if you want to access to this values).

As Entity Framework doesn't support `Geography` types/functions for now, I'm afraid your only option is to write a stored procedure that internally calls `STDistance` (if you use SQL Server 2008 R2).

Honestly, as the spatial functions actually depend on the database (`STDistance` is valid for SQL Server 2008 R2 only), it's not a bad idea to have stored procedure for your particular use case.

Comment: Starting with EF5, support for DbGeography was added. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is out of date. EF5 introduced API for working with spatial data. Here is an example from MSDN;

Model

```
using System.Data.Spatial; //For EF5
//using System.Data.Entity.Spatial; //For EF6

public class University  
{ 
    public int UniversityID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; } 
}
```

DbContext

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public partial class UniversityContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<University> Universities { get; set; } 
}
```

Persist and Retrieve data

```
using (var context = new UniversityContext ()) 
{ 
    context.Universities.Add(new University() 
        { 
            Name = "Graphic Design Institute", 
            Location = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-122.336106 47.605049)"), 
        }); 
 
    context. Universities.Add(new University() 
        { 
            Name = "School of Fine Art", 
            Location = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-122.335197 47.646711)"), 
        }); 
 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
 
    var myLocation = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-122.296623 47.640405)"); 
 
    var university = (from u in context.Universities 
                        orderby u.Location.Distance(myLocation) 
                        select u).FirstOrDefault(); 
 
    Console.WriteLine( 
        "The closest University to you is: {0}.", 
        university.Name); 
}
```

The above query result should be `The closest University to you is: School of Fine Art.`

See the [whole article and video here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/spatial)